# Токен. Как определить время, для рефреша токена?

Tags: php, token, jwt

Токен. Как определить время, для рефреша токена?

На сколько я понял, используя `accesstoken` ему можно передать значение полученое из `Unix timestamp`. На выходе что-то вроде `json` - `"expires_in": 1502305985425`. Как мне определить, что прошло, к примеру, минут 10? Каким-то образом отнимать записаное в `accesstoken` значение от текущего?

Если есть инструменты `JWT` для этого - буде идеально.
Спасибо!

Comment: Там где вам нужно проверить токен берете текущий timestamp и сравниваете с тем который в expires_in. Если текущий > expires_in то токен умер.

Comment: @EatMyDust, ну, я где-то так и думал. Спасибо! Давьте как ответ - отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там, где вам нужно проверить токен берете текущий timestamp и сравниваете с тем, который в expires_in. Если текущий > expires_in, то токен умер.